# Svelte [Client Side] The layout given to certain routes in router operations is applied to all routes

Tags: svelte

I have a Svelte [Client Side] project. I created a router structure. I added certain Routes to Layout. But Layout applies to all Routes.

```js
    <Router>
        <EmptyLayout>
            <Route path="/auth/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </EmptyLayout>
    </Router>
    <Router>
        <ContainerLayout>
            <PrivateRoute component={AddHouse} path="/house/add" />
            <PrivateRoute component={EditHouse} path="/house/edit/:id" />
            <PrivateRoute component={ViewHouse} path="/house/view/:id" />
            <PrivateRoute component={ListHouse} path="/house/list" />
            <PrivateRoute component={AddLand} path="/land/add" />
            <PrivateRoute component={EditLand} path="/land/edit/:id" />
            <PrivateRoute component={ViewLand} path="/land/view/:id" />
            <PrivateRoute component={ListLand} path="/land/list" />
            <PrivateRoute
                component={FindLocalPeople}
                path="/people/find/local"
            />
            <PrivateRoute
                component={FindGlobalPeople}
                path="/people/find/global"
            />
        </ContainerLayout>
    </Router>
```

[image: svelte page]

Comment: I am no Svelte guy, but should not there be some kind of `<Switch>` thing to avoid the same route being applied multiple times? They all match currently, right? Or is the svelte router exclusive by default

Comment: Here is an example, I just wanted to add a Layout. https://svelte.dev/repl/451fd183e0d3403cb7800101f7d799fb?version=3.53.0

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by creating custom route components.

```js
    <Router>
        <PublicRoute path="/auth/login" layout={EmptyLayout}><Login /></PublicRoute>
        <PublicRoute path="*" layout={EmptyLayout}><NotFound /></PublicRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/house/add" layout={ContainerLayout}><AddHouse /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/house/edit/:id" layout={ContainerLayout}><EditHouse /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/house/view/:id" layout={ContainerLayout}><ViewHouse /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/house/list" layout={ContainerLayout}><ListHouse /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/land/add" layout={ContainerLayout}><AddLand /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/land/edit/:id" layout={ContainerLayout}><EditLand /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/land/view/:id" layout={ContainerLayout}><ViewLand /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/land/list" layout={ContainerLayout}><ListLand /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/people/find/local" layout={ContainerLayout}><FindLocalPeople /></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/people/find/global" layout={ContainerLayout}><FindGlobalPeople /></PrivateRoute>
    </Router>
```